# How to transpose and multiply tensor with itself in pytorch

Tags: pytorch

What I have is the following tensor:

```
a = np.array([[1,1], [2,2], [3,3]])
t = torch.from_numpy(a)
```

I need an operation that gets me to the following matrix:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lx6Fn.png)

This matrix contains the element-wise dot product of the tensor if it gets multiplied by its transposed version, i.e., the first element on the diagonal is
1x1 + 1x1 = 2, the 2nd element on the diagonal is
2x2 + 2x2 = 8, and the 2nd element in the first column is 1x2 + 1x2 = 4,
and so on. How do I get this matrix in torch, starting from tensor t? Thank you!

I tried various combinations of torch.tensordot, torch.transpose, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`einsum` it!

```
print(torch.einsum("ik,jk->ij", t, t))
print(torch.einsum("ki,kj->ij", t, t))
```

---

```
tensor([[ 2,  4,  6],
        [ 4,  8, 12],
        [ 6, 12, 18]], dtype=torch.int32)
        
tensor([[14, 14],
        [14, 14]], dtype=torch.int32)
```